# Converting this scala code to C++

Tags: c++, scala

I have the following scala code:

```
val gates = varNode.getGates()
val inMsgs = gates.map(g => g.getEndGate.getMessage())
val variableMarginal = inMsgs.reduceLeft((msg1, msg2) => msg1 * msg2)
```

Is this the same as the following in C++ (assume we know the types and the underlying C++ container used is a vector)?

```
std::vector<Gate *> gates = varNode.getGates();
// Assume that the first gate always has a valid message
double marginal = gates[0]->getEndGate()->getMessage();
for (int i = 1; i < gates.size(); ++i)
    marginal *= gates[i]->getEndGate()->getMessage();
```

I am confused by the reduceLeft function. Cannot understand what it does.

[EDIT] The Gate class is defined as follows:

```
sealed abstract class Gate(initialMsg: SingleFactor) {

type END_GATE <: Gate

private var endGate: Option[END_GATE] = None

private var message: SingleFactor = initialMsg
private var oldMessage: SingleFactor = initialMsg
def setEndGate(gate: END_GATE) { endGate = Some(gate) }
def getEndGate(): END_GATE = endGate.get

def setMessage(newMessage: SingleFactor, msgIndex: Long) {
    oldMessage = message
    message = newMessage
}
def getMsgIndex(): Long = msgIndex
def getMessage(): SingleFactor = message
def getOldMessage(): SingleFactor = oldMessage
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing, what `Gate` actually is ...

Comment: Sorry. Added the Gate abstract class definition now. The concrete objects just override some stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you need the implementation of SingleFactor and know if it's * operator is not overloaded, then you can deduce what the reduceLeft is doing.

I assume inMsgs is a vector of SingleFactor elements (through the .getMessage()) after the map operation has completed.

The reduceLeft will grab the first SingleFactor and use the * operator against the second SingleFactor the result of that will use again the * operator against the third SingleFactor and so forth, resulting in one value which would be stored in the variableMarginal.

for some example usages of reduceLeft you can read this: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-reduceleft-examples

to diagnose what the reduce is doing you could also change the reduceLeft call to something like this: (assuming you're able to execute your given Scala code)

```
# the semicolons are not needed but are added in case you copy paste/single line the code
val variableMarginal = inMsgs.reduceLeft((msg1, msg2) => { 
    val result = msg1 * msg2; 
    println("msg1: "+ msg1 + " msg2: "+ msg2 + " result: "+result); 
    result })
```

I think you can 'emulate' the reduceLeft in C++ with accumulate (API can be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate )
In this case you provide a BinaryOperation that's the same as the Scala's * operation of SingleFactor.